# What is the logic behind string removal?

Tags: linux, bash

Can someone explain the logic behind the order of `.*` and `*.`? Why do they have to be swapped when I want to remove from front and remove from back?

```
# IP="1.2.3.4"

# echo ${IP%.*}
1.2.3

# echo ${IP#*.}
2.3.4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%.*` removes the last octet and the dot that *precedes* it. `#*.` removes the first octet and the dot that *follows* it. It's the preceding dot vs. following dot difference that explains why you swap the dot.

From the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> `${parameter#word}`
>   `${parameter##word}`
>
> - **Remove matching prefix pattern.**  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the  pattern  matches
>     the  beginning  of  the  value  of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
>        matching pattern (the `#` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `##` case) deleted.  If parameter is `@` or `*`,  the  pattern
>        removal  operation  is  applied  to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an
>        array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of  the  array  in  turn,  and  the
>        expansion is the resultant list.
>
> `${parameter%word}`
>   `${parameter%%word}`
>
> - **Remove matching suffix pattern.**  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches a
>           trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter  with  the
>           shortest  matching pattern (the `%` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `%%` case) deleted.  If parameter is `@` or `*`, the
>           pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.   If  parameter
>           is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the
>           expansion is the resultant list.